# Incorrectly redirect works in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, server-configuration

It is necessary to redirect to the main page from the addressees **1)** `https://mysite/?Itemid=389`
**2)**
 `https://mysite/2-uncategorised.html?Start=6` .

Here is an example of my .htaccess:

According to the first rule, 404 is triggered.
According to the second rule, nothing happens.
Tell me what the problem may be.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY} ^Itemid=(. *)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY} ^start=(. *)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /2-uncategorised.html$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your variable `%{QUERY}` is wrong. It should be `%{QUERY_STRING}` .

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me.